# Перевод из десятичной в шестнадцатеричную систему в PHP

Tags: php

Есть функция перевода чисел из десятичной в шестнадцатеричную систему счисления.

```
void ConvertNumber(__int64 nNum, char* szText)
{
    sprintf(szText,"%02I64X%012I64X",nNum&(__int64)0x00000000000000FF,(nNum>> (__int64)8));
}
```

Пример работы:

> `10-ная:4501598728   на выходе 16-ная:080000010C50F2`

Нужно всё это дело реализовать на php. Как думаете реально? Кто что посоветует? Заранее спасибо.

Думаем дальше.

Функция sprintf форматирует и запоминает наборы символов и значений в переменную в нашем случае szText. "`%02I64X%012I64X`"  - строка управления форматом. Честно говоря, хз как это понимать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// преобразование в десятичную систему
 print bindec(11011); // 27
 print octdec(33);    // 27
 print hexdec('1b');  // 27
 // преобразование из десятичной системы
 print decbin(27);    // 11011
 print decoct(27);    // 33
 print dechex(27);    // 1b
```

[здесь можно почитать подробней](http://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=98)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ссылочку.
Сейчас буду проверять.
Просто в этой функции есть Томский подвох.
Возможно что стандартными методами мы не отделаемся

Comment: Так и есть. Стандартными методами не получаеться.Выводиться не то что нужно=(

Comment: А что нужно? Можно подробней?

Comment: Вот 2 числа, одних и тех же только в разных с.и.
10-ная:4501598728  16-ная:080000010C50F2
и вот используя предложенные методы  никак не получаеться получить корректный перевод

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что 450159872 = вашему числу, а не просто 1 0C50 F208???

Comment: 450159872 это номер электронной карты(чипа). Что то на подобе
домофоновских. В нашей системе они указанны в десятичном формате.
а вот в самой базе ОС, они указанны в шестнад.. тоесть вот так
080000010C50F2.  У меня даже есть программа которая их переводит.
Постучите в асю, я вам её скину.

Comment: 498348534

Comment: Если я правильно понял, результат надо перегнать в формат, где последние две цифры ставятся в начало строки, остальное в конец, а середина забивается нулями?)

Answer (score 3):

А вам необходимо самому решить данную задачу или пойдет готовая функция?

Если готовая, то вот: `string dechex ( int $number )`, взята [здесь](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php).

И еще оттуда же, только из комментариев:

```
//I was confused by dechex's size limitation. Here is my solution to the problem. It
//supports much bigger values, as well as signs.

<?php 
function dec_to_hex($dec) 
 { 
     $sign = ""; // suppress errors 
     if( $dec < 0){ $sign = "-"; $dec = abs($dec); }

     $hex = Array( 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 
                   6 => 6, 7 => 7, 8 => 8, 9 => 9, 10 => 'a', 
                   11 => 'b', 12 => 'c', 13 => 'd', 14 => 'e',    
                   15 => 'f' );

     do 
     { 
         $h = $hex[($dec%16)] . $h; 
         $dec /= 16; 
     } 
     while( $dec >= 1 );

     return $sign . $h; 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: Самому решить или нет, это не важно.
Главное чтобы все коректно переводилось.

Comment: Увы тоже криво.=(